# Regex encapsulate full line and surround it

Tags: ruby, regex, markdown, pandoc

I can find examples of surrounding a line but not surrounding and replacing, and I'm a bit new to Regex.

I'm trying to ease up my markdown, so that I do not need to add in html just to get it to center images.

With pandoc, I apparently need to surround and image with DIV tags to get it to be centered, right justified, or what ever.

Instead of typing that every time, I'd like to just preprocess my markdown with a ruby script and have ruby add in the DIV's for me.

So I can type:

```
center![](image.jpg)
```

and then run a ruby script that will change it to

```
<div class="center">
![](image.jpg)
</div>
```

I want the regex to find "center!" and get rid of the word "center" and surround the rest with DIV tags.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: You might also want to have a look at http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/scripting.html But maybe even better: why not apply the CSS to all images instead of only to `img.center`?

Comment: I may want some centered, some left, some right, and I could not find how to pass a class name to an image in markdown that worked with pandoc. Also, if I get this to work I can do a lot of markdown customization for other types of things as well.  I'm new at this though, maybe i'm reinventing a wheel.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately images can't have attributes (like classnames) in Pandoc yet. There's an open [issue on that](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/261#issuecomment-50236381).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little example using `gsub`:

```
s = "a\ncenter![](image.jpg)\nb\n"
puts s.gsub(/^center(.*)$/, "<div class=\"center\">\n\\1\n</div>")
```

Result is:

```
a
<div class="center">
![](image.jpg)
</div>
b
```

Should get you started. The `(.*)` captures the content after center, and `\\1` adds it back into the replacement. In this example I assumed that the item was on a line by itself - `^` indicates the start of a line and `$` indicates the end of a line. If that isn't the case, you'll need to determine what makes what your regex unique so that it doesn't replace any random usage of "center" in your text.

Comment: yes probably always on its own line right at the start.  I think this is exactly what I was looking for.  Maybe I can make it more generic and do left!, right!, center! and then use the word before ! as the div's class (left, right, center)